# Replacing Empty Cells with 0 - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm **scraping** a COVID dataset using Python - BeautifulSoup and Selenium. The data frame has empty cells in some of the columns. However, I cannot convert it into 0.

I've exhausted all given solutions in stack overflow. I know its a repeat question, more like a silly one but I don't know how to resolve this.

This is the code:

```
def recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns):

    for column in list_of_columns:
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].replace('\xa0',0)
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].replace(" ",0)
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].fillna(0)

    return dataframe
recode_empty_cells(df, df.columns)
```

Comment: You should also mention the URL, your scraping code

Comment: without providing the url or the dataframe, not much anyone can do to help/give specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible there is more than 1 whitespace in the data. So what I would do is first `.strip()` the strings, then can do a replace on `''`.

Note: I don't know what your data looks like. This does not take care of any mixing of datatypes in the columns. If there's a mix of strings and ints in the column, we'll need to adjust this code. Also, are you sure you want to fill with `0` in all columns? I'm assuming some columns are not numerical that you have. But give this a try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'column A':['A','B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
                    'column B':['4','3',' ', ' 100', '   ', None, np.nan]})

print('Before: \n', df)


def recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns):
    for column in list_of_columns:
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].str.strip()
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].fillna(0)
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].replace("",0)
        
    return dataframe

recode_empty_cells(df, df.columns)

print('\n\nAfter: \n', df)
```

**Output:**

```
Before: 
   column A column B
0        A        4
1        B        3
2        C         
3        D      100
4        E         
5        F     None
6        G      NaN
    

After: 
   column A column B
0        A        4
1        B        3
2        C        0
3        D      100
4        E        0
5        F        0
6        G        0
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Yes, only numerical columns were empty, i.e. 0 case for the day.

Answer (score 1):

```py
dataframe.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Should work

Comment: Technically, yes. But as @chitwon88 pointed out, maybe there were more one whitespace which led to this unfunctional.